# Generate soap request using Camel

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel

I want to call third party webservice from camel using wsdl file without any generating client code(because i think if i am providing wsdl file then camel able to generate client that we previously generate and that's working in our older code)

After searching long time i found some code that helps me to achieve my goal

code is

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.Soap11DataFormatAdapter;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.Soap12DataFormatAdapter;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.name.ServiceInterfaceStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.SoapJaxbDataFormat;

import com.camel.model.Application;
public class TestMain {
    static CamelContext context;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate(0);
        context.start();
        String url="cxf://http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService?" +
          "wsdlURL=http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService?wsdl&" +
          "serviceName={http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com}ApplicationService&" +
          "portName={http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com}ApplicationServiceHttpPort&" +
          "dataFormat=MESSAGE";
        Exchange reply = sendSimpleMessage(template, url);
        org.apache.camel.Message out = reply.getOut();
        String result = out.getBody(String.class);

        System.out.println(result);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }

    private static Exchange sendSimpleMessage(ProducerTemplate template,
            String endpointUri) {


        Exchange exchange = template.request(endpointUri, new Processor() {
            public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                exchange.getIn().setBody("<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         + "<soap:Body><ns1:getApplication xmlns:ns1=\"http://cxf.component.camel.apache.org/\">"
//                         + "<arg0 xmlns=\"http://cxf.component.camel.apache.org/\">hello world</arg0>"
                         + "</ns1:getApplication></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");


                 System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            }
        });
        return exchange;
    }
}
```

this works correctly but here i am manually generate soap Envelop

wsdl file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com" xmlns:ns1="urn:http://model.application.buzzor.atpl.com" xmlns:soapenc12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:tns="http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com">
<xsd:element name="getApplication">
<xsd:complexType/>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="getApplicationResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="out" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="addApplication">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="in0" nillable="true" type="ns1:Application"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="in1" nillable="true" type="ns1:User"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="addApplicationResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="out" nillable="true" type="ns1:ApplicationResult"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:http://model.application.buzzor.atpl.com">
<xsd:complexType name="Application">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_PASSWORD" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_VERSION" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="EXCEPTION_HANDLED" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="IS_LOGIN_REQUIRED" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LONG_CODES" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PREVIOUS_NODE_KEY" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="REPLY_TEXT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="WELCOME_NOTE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="User">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ACTIVE_STATUS" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CUSTOMER_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="FIRST_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="IS_ADMIN" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LAST_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LOGIN_USER_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="LOGIN_ALLSC" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_ACTION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_CONFIRM_PASSWORD" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_PASSWORD" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_PATH" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_STATUS" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="USER_TYPE" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="VERSION_ID" type="xsd:double"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ApplicationResult">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="APP_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ERROR_MESSAGE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ERROR_STATUS" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="addApplicationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addApplication">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addApplicationResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addApplicationResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getApplicationResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getApplicationResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getApplicationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getApplication">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ApplicationServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getApplication">
      <wsdl:input name="getApplicationRequest" message="tns:getApplicationRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getApplicationResponse" message="tns:getApplicationResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addApplication">
      <wsdl:input name="addApplicationRequest" message="tns:addApplicationRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="addApplicationResponse" message="tns:addApplicationResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ApplicationServiceHttpBinding" type="tns:ApplicationServicePortType">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getApplication">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="getApplicationRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getApplicationResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addApplication">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="addApplicationRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="addApplicationResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ApplicationService">
    <wsdl:port name="ApplicationServiceHttpPort" binding="tns:ApplicationServiceHttpBinding">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

now i want to generate soap request rather that static

please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Changed my code as following
now it works fine but i think i am not using camel properly

so help me to improve generate soap request using camel without writing any java code.

```
package com.camel.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.message.CxfConstants;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CamelViralTest {
    static CamelContext context;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate(0);

        context.start();
        String url = "cxf://http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService?"
                + "wsdlURL=http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService?wsdl&"
                + "serviceName={http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com}ApplicationService&"
                + "portName={http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com}ApplicationServiceHttpPort"
        +"&dataFormat=MESSAGE";
        Exchange e=sendSimpleMessage1(template,url);
        System.out.println(e.getOut().getBody());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }

    private static Exchange sendSimpleMessage1(ProducerTemplate template,
            String endpointUri) {

        final List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, "getApplication");
        headers.put("requestObject", new DefaultCxfBinding());
        params.add("hello world");

        Exchange exchange = template.request(endpointUri, new Processor() {
            public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                SOAPMessage soapMessage=createSOAPRequest();
                exchange.getIn()
                        .setBody(  soapMessage.getSOAPBody());
            }
        });
        return exchange;

    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
         MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

            // SOAP Envelope
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

            javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
            SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("getApplication", "example");
           /* SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("data", "example");
            soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");*/
            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "getApplication");

            soapMessage.saveChanges();

            /* Print the request message */
            System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were using a JAXB entity instead of a String you could use the [SOAP data format](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html) to marshal it into a SOAP envelope. From that page...

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:start"/>
  <marshal>
     <soapjaxb contentPath="com.example.customerservice" version="1.2" elementNameStrategyRef="myNameStrategy"/>
  </marshal>
  <to uri="jms:myQueue"/>
</route>
```

Generally it is ill advised to hand write your XML as it's very error prone and you can't make use of these handy features. You'll also find it difficult to use any of the expression languages other than XPath against the plain string.

Comment: thanks for reply @James
When i am searching then i found some code like you posted
but i am not able to understand what is contextPath and elementNameStrategyRef

i have to create customerservice class? in com.example package?
if yes then why because wsdl file contains all details require to call web service

Comment: JAXWS relies on JAXB annotated classes to handle generation, parsing and navigation and camel in turn relies on these to perform it's work such as evaluation expressions. You'll find it much easier and you can generate the classes using a maven plugin or even from eclipse (right click WSDL > Generate JAXB classes or similar). I'm not familiar with any way to achieve what you want without it.

Comment: as you said i wrote following code but getting exception
`package com.atpl.buzzor.applicatiion.service;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(
    targetNamespace = "http://service.application.buzzor.atpl.com",
    name = "ApplicationService",
    serviceName = "ApplicationService",
    portName = "ApplicationServiceHttpPort"
  )
public interface ApplicationService {
 @WebMethod
 public void getApplication()
   throws Exception;
}`

that means i have to generate client stub and then i am able to generate soap request from that client?
please explain that

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am getting following error
`Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.atpl.buzzor.applicatiion.service" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.atpl.buzzor.applicatiion.service" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]`

Comment: When you generate the classes it creates one called ObjectFactory in the package alongside your service and entities. Have a look at the examples in the camel CXF documentation [http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html] and the examples linked there. They use maven to generate the artifacts which you use various plugins to do including the CXF one which is Camels default JAXWS impemenation. [http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html].

Answer (score 0):

1)  Let me call your wsdl file ***buzzor.wsdl***. Save your wsdl in your project Directory as below and then Generate classes from wsdl file using wsdl2java plugin. In your pom.xml add this.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/buzzor.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/buzzor.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                         <extraargs>
                          <!--this will generate client for you-->
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                   </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

You will see the generated classes as below..
[image]

***ApplicationServicePortType_ApplicationServiceHttpPort_Client.java*** is a sample client, which you can use to write your custom client if you want.

**in your case let us use ApplicationServicePortType.java which defines 2 methods**

```
a) public java.lang.String getApplication();
b) public http.model_application_buzzor_atpl.ApplicationResult addApplication(...);
```

**2) in your spring context configure the Jaxws client.**

```
<beans xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:client id="applicationService" serviceClass="com.atpl.buzzor.application.service.ApplicationServicePortType" address="http://localhost:8081/buzzor-service/services/ApplicationService" />
```

**3) in your Camel route you can invoke a bean...**

```
@Inject
private SoapUtils soapUtils;
...
from("direct:some-endpoint")
.bean(soapUtils,"invokeWebserviceAndGetResponse")
```

**4) in your SoapUtils class you can inject the applicationService bean and invoke the webservice**

```
import com.atpl.buzzor.application.service.ApplicationServicePortType;
import http.model_application_buzzor_atpl.ApplicationResult;
import http.model_application_buzzor_atpl.Application;
import http.model_application_buzzor_atpl.User;
public class SoapUtils {
    @Inject
    private ApplicationServicePortType applicationService;

    public void invokeWebserviceAndGetResponse(Exchange exchange) {
         java.lang.String response = applicationService.getApplication();
         ..or..
         Application application = new Application(); //or whichever way you generate this.
         User user = new User(); //or which ever way u generate this.
         ApplicationResult result = applicationService.addApplication(application,user);
         ...
    }
}
```